# PouchDB not able to insert multiple json files

Tags: storage, indexeddb, pouchdb

I am trying to store 3 different JSON Object's using PouchDB,

devices.json:

> [
>     {"id":"001","name":"iPhone","brand":"Apple","tags":["Apple","IOS"],"os":"IOS","Description":"...."},
>     {"id":"002","name":"galaxy","brand":"Samsung","tags":["Samsung","android"],"os":"android","Description":"...."},
>     {"id":"003","name":"nexus","brand":"Google","tags":["Google","android"],"Description":"...."},
>     {"id":"004","name":"galaxy
>   s4","brand":"Samsung","tags":["Samsung","android"],"os":"android","Description":"...."}
>   ]

brand.json:

> [
>       { "id": "001", "name": "Apple" },
>       { "id": "002", "name": "Samsung" },
>       { "id": "003", "name": "Google" } ]

And tags.json as

> [
>       { "id": "001", "name": "Apple" },
>       { "id": "002", "name": "Samsung" },
>       { "id": "003", "name": "Google" },
>       { "id": "004", "name": "IOS" },
>       { "id": "005", "name": "android" } ]

Here when i am inserting using db.bulkDocs() devices.json it's creating 7 tables in one database. Now am trying the same function to insert brands.json & tags.json. But its not able to insert to database.

My javascript code is

```js
var db = new PouchDB('dev');
var toinsert = ["devices","brands","tags"];
toinsert.forEach(function(json){
    insert(json);
})
function insert(json){
    var param2 = {
        url: json + '.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET'
    };
    $.ajax(param2)
        .done(function(data){
            db.bulkDocs(data).then(function (result) {
                console.log('Row inserted Successfully');
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Unable to insert into DB. Error: ' + err.name + ' - ' + err.message);
            });            
        });

}
```

Here when i am checking indexedDB i am getting only devices.json data, Others are missing. Here I am not sure weather PouchDB can insert multiple json files or not? If it's Possible using PouchDB, Please helm me to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the second and third objects are not a valid json object. This could be the issue, check http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json objects.